# my tic tac toe ai is not working . is there a way to fix it?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, cs50, tic-tac-toe

```
"""
Tic Tac Toe Player
"""

import math
import copy
X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = None


def initial_state():
    """
    Returns starting state of the board.
    """
    return [[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]]


def player(board):
    """
    Returns player who has the next turn on a board.
    """
    countx=0
    counto=0
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if board[i][j]==X:
                countx+=1
            if board[i][j]==O:
                counto+=1

    if counto>countx:
        return X
    if countx>counto:
        return O
                
                

    


def actions(board):
    """
    Returns set of all possible actions (i, j) available on the board.
    """
    allaction=set()
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if board[i][j]==EMPTY:
                print(i,j)
                allaction.add((i,j))
    
    return allaction
    


def result(board, action):
    """
    Returns the board that results from making move (i, j) on the board.
    """
    current_player=player(board)
    new_all_actions=actions(board)
    if action not in  new_all_actions:
        raise Exception("move not in the set ")
    i,j=action 
    copy_board=copy.deepcopy(board)
    copy_board[i][j]=current_player
    return copy_board
        

def check_row(board,player):
    for i in range(0,3):
        if board[i][0]==player and board[i][1]==player and board[i][2]==player:
            return True
    return False
def check_column(board,player):
    for i in range(len(board)-1):
        if board[0][i]==player and board[1][i]==player and board[2][i]==player:
            return True
    return False

def check_diagonals(board,player):
    if board[0][0]==player and board[1][1]==player and board[2][2]==player:
        return True
    elif board[0][2]==player and board[1][1]==player and board[2][0]==player:
        return True
    return False

def winner(board):
    """
    Returns the winner of the game, if there is one.
    """
    
    if check_column(board,X)==True or check_row(board,X)==True or check_diagonals(board,X)==True:
        return X
    elif check_column(board,O)==True or check_row(board,O)==True or check_diagonals(board,O)==True:
        return O
    return None
    


def terminal(board):
    """
    Returns True if game is over, False otherwise.
    """
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if board[i][j]==EMPTY:
                return False
    if winner(board)==X or winner(board)==O:
        return True
    else:
        return True
    
    

    
        
        


def utility(board):
    """
    Returns 1 if X has won the game, -1 if O has won, 0 otherwise.
    """
    if terminal(board)==False:
        raise Exception("game not over")
    if winner(board)==X:
        return 1
    if winner(board)==O:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

def max_value(board):
        v=-math.inf
        if terminal(board):
            return utility(board)
        for action in actions(board):
            v=max(v,min_value(result(board,action)))
        return v
        
def min_value(board):
    v=math.inf
    if terminal(board):
        return utility(board)
    for action in actions(board):
        v=min(v,max_value(result(board,action)))
    return v 

def minimax(board):
    if terminal(board):
        return None
    elif player(board)==X:
        max_variable=-math.inf
        max_index=0
        score_play=[]
        for action in actions(board):
            score_play.append(min_value(result(board,action)),action)
        for i in range(len(score_play)-1):
            if score_play[i][0]>max_variable:
                max_variable=score_play[i][0]
                max_index=i
        
        return score_play[max_index][1]
    
#its returns min of max_value of all possible boards from the result
    elif player(board)==O:
       
        min_varible=math.inf
        min_index=0
        score_play=[]
        for action in actions(board):
            score_play.append(max_value(result(board,action),action))
        for j in range(len(score_play)-1):
            if score_play[j][0]<min_varible:
                min_varible=score_play[j][0]
                min_index=j
        for q in score_play[min_index][1] :
            print(q)
        return score_play[min_index][1]
```

this is my code for a tic tac toe ai. On runnig it it shows the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\tictactoe\tictactoe\runner.py", line 116, in 
> board = ttt.result(board, move)
> File "C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\tictactoe\tictactoe\tictactoe.py", line 66, in result
> raise Exception("move not in the set ")
> Exception: move not in the set

on further looking i got to know that the action passed to the result function is none but dont know why

I tried debugging it for a long time . the only error that can happen is maybe in the minmax function

Comment: Please provide a [_minimal_ reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If not all 9 squares are occupied, but one player has three in a row, `terminal()` should return True. However in your code it returns False. (Not sure if this is the only problem.)

Comment: Your `player` function doesn't return anything if `counto` and `countx` have the same value (which is the default, as they are both - correctly - initialized to 0)

Comment: This code seems to be from the module `ttt` imported in another file of yours so, can you provide the file that actually executes the function? Try not to upload whole chunks of code and ask to debug, rather use debugging tools in your ide to find general bugs. There is a lot of info provided in [project's page](https://cs50.harvard.edu/ai/2020/projects/0/tictactoe/) itself. Also, there is SO network for [`CS50`](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are these issues:

- `terminal` returns `False` for any board that has an empty spot. You should only start the empty spot check when it is already verified that there is no winner. NB: the `if..else` is overkill, since in both cases you return True, so just ... return True without condition. Also, you can use the `in` operator to check if a row has `EMPTY`:

  ```
  def terminal(board):
      if not winner(board):  # Only check for empty spot when no winner
          for row in board:
              if EMPTY in row:
                  return False
      return True  # No condition needed
  ```
- `player` can return `None` when the two counters are equal. The function should never return `None`. Assuming X is the first player, you should return X when the count is equal and O otherwise:

  ```
      if counto==countx:
          return X
      return O
  ```
- `check_column` only iterates twice with `range(len(board)-1)`, but it should iterate 3 times. So:

  ```
  for i in range(len(board)):  # not -1 !!
  ```
- In `minimax` parentheses are put wrongly in `score_play.append(max_value(result(board,action),action))`. Both `max_value` and `append` should be called with one argument, so:

  ```
  score_play.append((max_value(result(board,action)),action))
  ```

  A similar change is needed where you call `min_value`
- In `minimax` the loop over `score_play` does not visit the last entry when having `range(len(score_play)-1)`. The loop should be:

  ```
  for i in range(len(score_play)):
  ```

  Change this in both places where this occurs.

NB: You could have detected all of these issues yourself if you would have used a debugger, stepping through the code, setting break points and inspecting variables.

Comment: Thank you I was able to fix it. As you mentioned player function was the problem and I also fixed minimax